MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED: Error al conectar múltiples microservicios nestjs a bd mongo en entorno productivo docker
Estoy tratando de generar un entorno productivo en un contenedor docker para una aplicación de microservicios, pero cuando intento que los microservicios se comuniquen con su respectiva base de datos obtengo error de conexión

docker-compose.yaml del proyecto completo:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq_ahora-sports
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: user
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: password
    networks:
      - ahora-network

  users_db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: users_db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./app_data/users_db:/data/db
    networks:
      - ahora-network

  players_db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: players_db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "27019:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./app_data/players_db:/data/db
    networks:
      - ahora-network

  teams_db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: teams_db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./app_data/teams_db:/data/db
    networks:
      - ahora-network

  matches_db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: matches_db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "27020:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./app_data/matches_db:/data/db
    networks:
      - ahora-network

  api-gateway:
    build: ./api-gateway
    image: api-gateway-ahora-sports
    container_name: api-gateway-ahora-sports
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - ahora-network

  users-ms:
    build: ./microservice-users
    image: microservice-users-ahora-sports
    container_name: ms-users-ahora-sports
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - users_db
    networks:
      - ahora-network

  players-ms:
    build: ./microservice-players
    image: microservice-players-ahora-sports
    container_name: ms-players-ahora-sports
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - players_db
    networks:
      - ahora-network
  teams-ms:
    build: ./microservice-teams
    image: microservice-teams-ahora-sports
    container_name: ms-teams-ahora-sports
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - teams_db
    networks:
      - ahora-network

  matches-ms:
    build: ./microservice-match
    image: microservice-matches-ahora-sports
    container_name: ms-matches-ahora-sports
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - matches_db
    networks:
      - ahora-network

networks:
  ahora-network:
    driver: bridge

Los antecedentes son los siguientes:

El microservicio de usuarios logra establecer conexión con la base de datos.

Cuando levanto los microservicios en modo desarrollo logran conectarse porque ya he hecho pruebas de los endpoint crud.
Si por ejemplo a cualquier microservicio le asigno el puerto

.env productivo ms-usuarios:
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MONGO_DB=db_users
MONGO_PORT=27017
MONGO_HOST=users_db
MONGO_CONNECTION=mongodb

#RabbitMQ
AMQP_URL=amqp://user:password@rabbitmq_ahora-sports:5672

.env productivo ms-teams
#Database Connection
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MONGO_DB=db_teams
MONGO_PORT=27018
MONGO_HOST=teams_db
MONGO_CONNECTION=mongodb

#RabbitMQ
AMQP_URL=amqp://user:password@rabbitmq_ahora-sports:5672

he probado de todo ya y las soluciones tradicionales no han funcionado:

revisar variables de entorno
revisar conexiones a las bases de datos
revisar codigo relacionado
y nada de eso ha funcionado porque el error es de conexion y no de programacion

codigo del modulo de conexion a base de datos
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigType } from '@nestjs/config';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import config from '../config';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [config.KEY],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigType<typeof config>) => {
        const { connection, user, password, host, port, dbName } =
          configService.mongo;
        return {
          uri: `${connection}://${user}:${password}@${host}:${port}/${dbName}?authSource=admin`,
          user,
          pass: password,
          dbName,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  exports: [MongooseModule],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}



Comparte el código de Nest.

Creo que es innecesario ya que todos los ms tienen el mismo modulo de conexion a la bd, hay un microservicio que se conecta por ende si está correcto. y reitero que en modo desarrollo si funcionan todos correctamente. ```

